# Interacting with a linux input kernel driver from userspace

Tags: drivers, kernel, input

I'm developing a linux kernel driver for a multitouch device. Right now I have already touch being injected to the linux kernel subsystem and it is working. The problem is that I also need to interact with the device to change settings an so on.

While the kernel is grabbing the device I can't grab it in user space, so I need to find a way to interact with the kernel driver.

My first driver test had some extra operations that I can't find on the current model i'm using. It had open, close, read, write operatins that I could perform from user space.

How can I do such things with input drivers? Is there any official way?

Thanks in advance,

With my best regards,

Nuno Santos

Comment: I ended up implementing binary attributes for my device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement character device injected into the kernel standard input subsystem. Please check [this](http://elinuxdd.com/) book. The `read()`, `write()`, `ioctl()`, etc. are typical char drivers operations, any char driver has at least `open()` and `close()`.
 Anyway, what subsystem of kernel did you use in your last driver version? Most useful way for any kernel development is to read related documents in Documentation/ of kernel sources directory and read the kernels drivers code of area related with your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your input device driver with a character driver and then you get a device file which you can write your configuration data to and read the configuration from. Interaction between two seperated drivers in kernel space should as well be not complicated.

I guess you already know this book, it might answer your question in detail:

[Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

Comment: which book? link is missing. thx

Comment: sorry... the link was not shown correctly as it had an offset of 4 characters in front and was shown as code